# Can i wire two switches so that the circuit is closed when one or both switches are thrown?

Tags: wiring

I basically want my switches to act like a logical OR, so that when one, the other, or both doors are opened, a common light turns on.

Comment: It be easier if it was when the switch closes. Two in parallel would do that. Otherwise an actual OR IC and a relay circuit is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply wire the two switches in parallel, like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOmyce.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I think they want opposite logic.

Comment: @Passerby:  They want the light on when the door opens - I assume they can figure out that the switch should close when the door opens (but perhaps not, if they had to ask...)

Comment: Use an old car door switch which makes contact when the door is open. Then wire up as shown above.